# How to override mixins in LESS CSS 1.4+

Tags: css, less

I've been using what I thought was a very elegant pattern for defining the styles of reusable components/widgets, using LESS. It works beautifully in LESS 1.3-, but after upgrading recently, my whole library is broken. Does anyone know a way to accomplish something like this in 1.4+?

Here's a very simple example of a component:

```
#componentName {
  .loadMixins(){
    .text() {}
    .header() {}
  }

  .apply(){
    > h3 {
      // markup-specific styles
      padding: 3px;
      margin-bottom: 0;

      // custom styles
      .header();
    }

    > div.body, > div.popup p {
      color: red;

      // custom styles
      .text()
    }
  }
}
```

And here's how it would be used:

```
.coolWidget {
  #componentName.loadMixins();

  // override mixins here
  .text(){
    color: green;
  }

  #componentName.apply();
}
```

This keeps all the markup-dependent styles abstracted from the user. I could completely change my markup and the user's styles would still work. According to the [less.js changelog](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), 1.4.0 Beta 1 has a line "variables in mixins no longer 'leak' into their calling scope"

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking nested variables and mixins are still expanded into calling scope unless this scope already has those names defined.

Your example above results in a error:

```
SyntaxError: .header is undefined...
```

and it's expected as no .header() is actually defined within the .coolWidget (or anywhere else).
This can be fixed by providing "default" definitions for .text and .header somewhere inside #componentName. 
For example if you modify .loadMixins() to:

```
.loadMixins() {
    .text();
    .header();

    // default properties in case a caller does not provide its own:
    .text()   {}
    .header() {}
}
```

then the example compiles OK and all text/header properties are overridden as expected.

---

I can imagine how your library may become broken because of new scope rules but this particular example you gave above does not illustrate the problem.

Comment: Hi Max! Thanks so much for the answer – you are right, I mistyped my example – the .loadMixins() mixin is supposed to set defaults. Just made an example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGyHb and it looks like they use 1.3.x so overrides are working. If you run it in 1.4.x, though, no dice :( I'd love to find another way to do this.

Comment: Of course my answer above is about 1.4.x (I tested with lescc 1.4.2 and 1.5.0-b2) where this code still works (and there's no reason why it should not).

Comment: You, sir, are totally right – I just ran this in a different environment and it worked. Looks like I have an environment-specific problem. Thanks so much for the help and for all your time!